# Check for LastWriteTime of directory\file an array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, filesystems, .net

I want the LastWritetTime of a couple of files, but the path to those files are in an array.

```
string[] array1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"path", "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string name in array1)
{
   Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

The output works, it shows a long list with the full path C:\etc\etc\etc.

But I found this code somewhere on stackoverflow

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"path");

Console.WriteLine("Checking file: " + file.Name);
Console.WriteLine("File exists: " + file.Exists.ToString());

if (file.Exists)
{
   Console.WriteLine(file.CreationTime.ToString());
   Console.WriteLine(file.LastWriteTime.ToString());
   Console.WriteLine(file.LastAccessTime.ToString());
}
```

This one also works, but I was wondering if these 2 codes could somehow be combined into 1.
I already tried: `FileInfo file = new FileInfo(array1");` but it was already obvious that that wouldn't work.

I am a learning student, so lots of explanation would be great! :)

If anyone can help me out with this, or at least give me something to start with, I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: I think any answer would give the game away so look at changing `@"path"` to something that exists in the foreach from first snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give path taken from `Directory.GetFiles` to the `FileInfo` constructor inside loop, as below

```
string[] array1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"path", "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string name in array1)
{

    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(name);

    Console.WriteLine("Checking file: " + file.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("File exists: " + file.Exists.ToString());

    if (file.Exists)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(file.CreationTime.ToString());
       Console.WriteLine(file.LastWriteTime.ToString());
       Console.WriteLine(file.LastAccessTime.ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I worked on this all week, I've tried lots of codes but nothing worked till now. But this does exactly what I want it to do! I can finally have a good sleep. THANK YOU AGAIN!

Comment: One final thing; could it be possible, in this code, to also put the directory path in front of the filename at `Console.WriteLine("Checking file: " + file.Name);`?

Answer (score 1):

Damiths answer is what my original comment was suggesting but I'll try to explain a bit about whats happening

- As you said, `GetFiles` returns an array of the full paths to the files
- `FileInfo`, takes in a path to a file as a parameter

You could even miss out the `if(File.Exists)` because since you already returned them from a directory, you know they exist

Answer (score 0):

If you use `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` instead of `Directory.GetFiles()` then you get back an array of `FileInfo`, rather than an array of `string`, so:

```
var fileInfoArray = DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(@"path");

foreach(var fInfo in fileInfoArray)
{
   Console.WriteLine(fInfo.CreationTime.ToString());
   Console.WriteLine(fInfo.LastWriteTime.ToString());
   Console.WriteLine(fInfo.LastAccessTime.ToString());
}
```